# cast existing Button to IPy subclass

Tags: ironpython, winforms

I have a test harness that runs in an embedded IronPython engine in our C# app.  Some of the tests are UI automation that simulate button clicks, etc.

```
# assume code to find an existing button, 'b' is an instance of System.Windows.Forms.Button
b.OnClick(EventArgs())
```

The issue I have is that the above code works on IPy 2.0.2 and not on 2.6.  Reading the link below, I can see why it no longer works.

http://dlr.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=57324

So I created a python sublclass as follows:

```
class PyButton(Button):pass
```

This works fine if you are going to create a new instance of PyButton and attempt the OnClick().  However, in my case, I need to perform an OnClick against an existing Button.  Essentially I want to do the following, to allow me to simulate the click on the button:

- Get a reference to existing winforms Button
- Cast/convert Button to custom PyButton subclass (to allow for OnClick)
- Call OnClick

I tried using [clr.Convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439457/can-you-typecast-a-net-object-in-ironpython):

```
import clr
from System.Windows.Forms import *
class PyButton(Button):pass
# assume b = existing button
pb = clr.Convert(b, clr.GetClrType(PyButton))
```

... but get this error:

```
expected Button_2$2, got Button
  input was pb = clr.Convert(b, clr.GetClrType(PyButton))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't - just like you can't call it from C# or VB.Net or other .NET languages without having a subclass.  Instead you probably want to call [Button.PerformClick()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx)

Comment: Alas - Button.PerformClick() works fine in the case of Button, but it looks to me like Button is the only control with that method. In the more general case, I need to do clicks on other objects as well, such as menu items. I ended up using reflection to get at OnClick (as well as some of the other user input events). Thanks!