# how to convert “var f = userState as Fault” from c# to ironpython

Tags: c#, silverlight, ironpython

I want to convert C# statement

```
   var f = userState as Fault
```

to ironpython statement

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this.

If you are  just trying to cast userState to a Fault then you don't need to do anything as Python is weakly typed.

If you are trying to determine if userState is of type Fault then try this

```
from System import *
if userState.GetType() == Type.GetType(Fault):
    ...
```

Comment: Not weakly typed, dynamically typed. Weak typing is a horrible concept that should only exist in terrible scripting languages.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the next line, it's hard to know what your intent is.

If you're downcasting (say from `object` to `Fault`) - you don't have to! In IronPython members are looked up at runtime, so if `userState` is already a `Fault` you can treat it as one without any casting.

If you're trying to trigger an explicit/implicit conversion, [use `clr.Convert`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439457/can-you-typecast-a-net-object-in-ironpython/1440427#1440427).

If you're checking if `userState` is a `Fault`, use `isinstance(userState, Fault)`.