# Get Revit Link Instance using Python

Tags: python, revit-api, revitpythonshell

Im new to the Revit API. I can get the Revit link instance using C# with the code below.

```
Element e = doc.GetElement(r);

if (e is RevitLinkInstance)
{
    //Get revit link instance
    RevitLinkInstance linkInstance = e as RevitLinkInstance;
    LinkedDocument = linkInstance.GetLinkDocument();

    //Do something
}
```

How do i get the LinkInstance using python.
What i have tried so far.

```
 element = doc.GetElement(ref)

 if element is RevitLinkInstance:
    linkInstance = #need to get link instance here#
    linked_document = linkInstance.GetLinkDocument()
```

Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C# sample statement `e as RevitLinkInstance` performs a .NET cast. Hence, you can answer this question by searching the Internet for [.net cast python](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=.net+cast+python), leading, e.g., to the question and answer [can you typecast a .NET object in IronPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439457/can-you-typecast-a-net-object-in-ironpython) The suggestion given there is to use

```
import clr
convertedObject = clr.Convert(someObject, someType)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy 
That worked perfectly. 

`linkInstance = clr.Convert(element, type(element))`

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation. Please up-vote the answer, then. Cheers!